# How to add custom callback to jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, callback, jquery-select2

I would like to add a custom function to Select2 plugin (but I don't have the necessary knowledge), like

```
$('.select2').select2({
    optionDrawCallback : function(li_element){
        return li_element.className += 'bg-'+li_element.text;
    }
});
```

Then I went to source code ([select2.full.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.full.js)) and found where each option element is created, which is here:

```
Results.prototype.option = function (data) {...}
```

But now I can't find out how to trigger my function.
I was able to trigger it over the `dataAdapter`, which should be the select itself, but that's not what I need.

Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: Give an example of how you want to call the function

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer:**

You should consider **avoiding** getting into the code of a 3rd party library and changing it, since your change will be overridden in a future versions (assuming you get them), and you'll have to figure out again where to put it in.

Every 3rd party plugin / library has its own way of work and API that should be worked with. Look for what you need in the documentation. If you're missing something, maybe there is a reason for it, or you can ask the developer to add it, or even do that yourself and create a pull request.

There is no "magic solution" for passing a callback for all libraries, since they all do different things, and each should be handled differently.

Can you say you would always need a callback before things start happening, maybe after, maybe both or even during the library's action?

As you can see, it really depends on what your library of choice does and how it does it. If there is a callback option in the documentation - it would probably be implemented in a way that would make sense, in one or more of the possible ways I mentioned above.

---

As for your specific case with the **select2** plugin:

Look into the [Templating](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating) option in the docs.

Here is an example of how to achieve what you ask for.

```js
var data = [{
  id: 0,
  text: 'gray'
}, {
  id: 1,
  text: 'green'
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'blue'
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: 'yellow'
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: 'red'
}];

function formatState(state) {
  var $state = $('<div class="bg-' + state.text + '" style="background-color: ' + state.text + ';" > ' + state.text + '</div>')
  return $state;
};

$('.select2').select2({
  data: data,
  templateResult: formatState
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="select2">
</select>
```

Here it is in a JsFiddle if you will: https://jsfiddle.net/yq70y8cy/1/

**Old answer:**

You should consider **avoiding** getting into the code of a 3rd party library and changing it, since your change will be overridden in a future versions (assuming you get them), and you'll have to figure out again where to put it in.

Instead, try keeping it simple, by using regular jQuery / javascript code, e.g:

```
$('.select2 li').each(function(index){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.addClass('bg-' + $this.text());
})
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but li elements are created and appended to body only after opening the dropdown..

Comment: In that case you could set the select element to be initially hidden using css, do you JS magic, and show it right after that's done (it should only take a fraction of a second).

Comment: Take a look at what happens to DOM when you use a select2 element. It's not that easy like you can think.

Comment: I looked at the examples on their website, from what I see you could use css-like selector to target the correct `<li>` element (e.g. 
`$('.select2 li[role=treeitem])`, of course this might change a little bit depending on the exact configuration you chose.
For example, Go to [their example page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) and paste the following code in the browser console : `$(".select2-dropdown li[role=treeitem]")`, it will log all the correct `<li>`s of the second example in that page.

Comment: But that is not there at DOM load, it is appended to body only if you click on `select`. If you look at html while clicking on the `select`, you will see a `span` with classes `select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open` appendend to the body, and when `select` is closed it is removed. That said, having a callback allowing me to add a class while that list element is generated would be much faster than looping each click

Comment: I see what your saying and totally agree about the speed issue. So after further looking, there is actually an option to pass a callback to each element while it is being generated, and that is the [Templating](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating) option. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Sorry, I can't accept the answer as it doesn't really solve my problem. I didn't necessary need to edit Select2 plugin, but it was for a more general prupose of knowledge about how to deal with 3rd party libraries

Comment: In that case you should have had described your question differently. Your main question is very general, and the question body look like it addresses a specific case you encountered, with the "select2" plugins. You explicitly say in your question body : "I would like to add a custom function to Select2 plugin" and give an example about just that plugin, even when asked by a commenter of the  question to give an example, you said it is the "select2" example. Also, you tagged this question with the select2 plugin, meaning it is a part of you problem.

Comment: Every 3rd party plugin/ library has its own code and API that should be worked with. Look for what you need in the documentation. If you're missing something, maybe there is a reason for it, or you can ask the developer to add it, or even do that yourself and create a pull request.

Comment: yes, I asked about Select2 because I want to add the callback to that plugin, but I would learn from the answer how to deal with other plugins.. My question is very simple and nobody gave me the answer I was expecting, just a workaround. (which works perfectly, thanks for that).
I would really like to do that myself but I miss those knowledges that would let me do it...

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details about what you ask for in your general question.

Answer (score 0):

I added a callback using `on` jquery function for click event of class `select2` which shows the default/selected option. This works fine as far as markup structure for select2 will remain the same.
Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmamx2xq/2/) for demo.

```
$('.select2').on('click', function(li_element){
    $(this).siblings(".select2-container--open").find(".select2-results__option").each(function(index,el) {
        console.log($(el).text());
        $(el).addClass('bg-' + $(el).text());
    });
});
```